# Best way to add accent to letter?

Tags: c#

I know the accent i want to add to the letter `ex: "´"` and i know the letter i want to add it to `ex:"a"`, and i want the final result to be `á`. But this has to work with at least 5 letters: `a,e,i,o,u` AND 4 accent `"´","`","^","~"`.Right now i am working on a function with several diferente`case's`. Is there a better way to do this?

Method i am using right now:
Letra: letter ; caraterEspecial: specialCharater

```
switch (caraterEspecial)
            {
                case "´":
                    switch (letra)
                    {
                        case "a":
                            letra= "á";
                            break;
                        case "e":
                            letra= "é";
                            break;
                        case "i":
                             letra= "í";
                            break;
                        case "o":
                             letra= "ó";
                            break;
                        case "u":
                             letra= "ú";
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "`":
                    switch (letra)
                    {
                        case "a":
                            letra= "à";
                            break;
                        case "e":
                            letra= "è";
                            break;
                        case "i":
                            letra= "ì";
                            break;
                        case "o":
                            letra= "ò";
                            break;
                        case "u":
                            letra= "ù";
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "~":
                    switch (letra)
                    {
                        case "a":
                            letra= "ã";
                            break;
                        case "o":
                            letra = "õ";
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case "^":
                    switch (letra)
                    {
                        case "a":
                            letra= "â";
                            break;
                        case "e":
                            letra= "ê";
                            break;
                        case "i":
                            letra= "î";
                            break;
                        case "o":
                            letra= "ô";
                            break;
                        case "u":
                            letra = "û";
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
```

For the accepted answer is a good list to use:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/list.htm

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+add+diacritical+marks, in particular http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net shows reverse process which will help with finding right methods

Comment: @TimSchmelter If you do not have an answer to give please don't assume things. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a Unicode [combining acute accent (U+0301)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm). This will generate a 2-character sequence that is displayed as a character with accent.

If needed, you can normalize this string to a canonical form.

Ex.:

```
string s = "a";
s += "\u0301";
s = s.Normalize();
```

Comment: Note that this is still extremely culture specific, so it's not necessarily any better from simply having a dictionary for the mappings or something like that. Unicode tricks are fun, but different languages still treat similar concepts differently.

Comment: When i try to use this code: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/223c/index.htm

They stay separated. How do i fix it?

Comment: you have to watch out that you use _combining_ characters. combining tilde is U+0303

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can use the replace method, but your question is incomplete. 
You should send the function , piece of code.

I would just use a `s.replace('a','á')`, maybe it's banal, but you don't have to deal too much, if letters are single like that.

Comment: That does not work because i need it for 5 letters and 4 accent.