# Is there a font to support "made up" Unicode combining characters?

Tags: c#, unicode, fonts

I'm trying to create a language as a world-building aspect of my project, and I have the intention of having an `m` with a `caron` above it as one of the characters in this language. I'm using WPF. I tried Segoe UI, Calibri, Cambria Math, Global Serif, Times New Roman... None of them work. Is there one which does?

Following the advice given by this answer [Best way to add accent to letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602219/best-way-to-add-accent-to-letter) I tried this:

```
string result = 'm'.ToString()
result += "\u02C7";
result.Normalize();
```

The `charon` is not displayed above the `m`, but to its right instead, like so:

`mˇ`

Comment: Are you asking if there is an existing unicode character that looks like what you're talking about? If so, check out: https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html Or are you asking if you can construct some arbitrary character? If so, no; unicode is a standard. Depending on how you're displaying, you may be able to make it kind of work how you're expecting, by printing 2 characters on top of each other

Comment: `02c7` is not a combining character. Try [`u30c`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030c/index.htm) instead

Comment: I was asking about Unicode's combining characters used to create arbitrary characters, but displaying the characters on top of each other will solve my problem. I didn't think of that. Thank you @Jonathan

Comment: @stuartd Works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `U+030C COMBINING CARON`, not `U+02C7 CARON`:

```
string result = 'm'.ToString()
result += "\u030C";
```

or:

```
string result = "m" + "\u030C";
```

or simply:

```
string result = "m\u030C";
```

or directly:

```
string result = "m̌"; // "\u006D\u030C"
```